# JaCoCo causes exceptions when running with Spring MockMvc

Tags: java, spring, jacoco

I am adding the JaCoCo code coverage plugin to an application with an end goal of seeing the report on Sonar. Without JaCoCo all of my tests pass, but adding it creates all sorts of problems. The first I notice is that building a MockMvc gives a NullPointerException.

Here is the init function I would like to run in one of my tests:

```
@Before
public void init() throws Exception {
    this.mockMvc = MockMvcBuilders.standaloneSetup(controller).build();
}
```

However, adding JaCoCo causes a NullPointerException, specifically from the build function. Why?

Edit: forgot to add that I have tried all the newest versions of all plugins, java, maven, etc.

Comment: Please be more specific: how are you running the test? Which versions are you using? What is the full stacktrace?

Answer (score 0):

Downgrading JaCoCo from 0.8.10 to 0.8.3 solved all my issues.